# Finding a basis for a set of points in plane and a lattice.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, lattice-orders, transformational-geometry

Suppose my domain is $\mathbb{R}^3$ where I have:

- a set of points $A = \left\lbrace x_i \right\rbrace_{i=1}^{n_1} $ and $n_1 > 3$.
- $A$ is contained in a plane (2-dimensional) $P_1$. i.e. $A \subset P_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.
- There is no basis $ \left( v_1, v_2, v_3 \right)$ for $A$ $\textit{and}$ a lattice $\Lambda \subset P_1$

I want to construct a mapping, $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto B$, such that:

- There exists a basis $ \left( w_1, w_2, w_3 \right)$ for $f(A)$ $\textit{and}$ $f(A*) \subset f(P_1)$ where $f(A) \cup f(A*)$ is a lattice in $B$.  That is to say $$\left(f(A) \cup f(A*) \right) \subset f(P_1) \subset B$$
- I can derive/define $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ algebraically. i.e.
  $$\begin{array}{rcl}
  w_1&=& \text{equation}_1 \in B\\
  w_2&=& \text{equation}_2 \in B\\
  w_3&=& \text{equation}_3 \in B\\
  \end{array}$$
- $f$ is bijective.

How do I do this?  I figure $f$ would need to be a piece-wise shearing function where it takes $A$ as input and then $f$ finds some other set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the the mapped union of those sets forms a lattice in $B$.  Although I am not sure.

Comment: What's $A*{}{}$?

Comment: Are there any conditions on $f$ and $B$? At first I assumed $B$ was a vector space and $f$ linear but then $f(A)$ would be at most 2-dimensional.

Comment: @joriki $A*$ is an arbitrary collection of points in $P_1$.  i.e. $A* \subset P_1$.  I believe this does imply the necessity of $f$ being injective when restricted to to the domain $P_1$.

Comment: @SimonMarkett the only condition is $f$ is bijective. $B$ is a codomain.  Ideally I would like to say that $B = \mathbb{R}^3$.  $f(A)$ need not be 2-dimensional.  $f$ may or may not be linear.   I would like to derive a function that that constructs a lattice given a collections of points in a plane.  The best tool I've seen that may be of use to me is Schinzel's Theorem and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KulikowskisTheorem.html